# Obtain all possible matrices by swapping only two positions in any given column

Tags: r

Let's start with the following matrix.

```
M <- matrix(c(0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,
          0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,
          0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,
          0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,
          0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,
          0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1),nrow = 8,ncol = 6)
```

Here is the `M`

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    1    0    1
[3,]    1    1    0    0    1    1
[4,]    1    0    0    1    1    0
[5,]    0    0    1    1    1    1
[6,]    0    1    1    0    1    0
[7,]    1    1    1    1    0    0
[8,]    1    0    1    0    0    1
```

If I pick a random column, say 4, I want to swap two positions in that column. One such possibility is swapping 5th and 6th position is given by

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    1    0    1
[3,]    1    1    0    0    1    1
[4,]    1    0    0    1    1    0
[5,]    0    0    1    0    1    1
[6,]    0    1    1    1    1    0
[7,]    1    1    1    1    0    0
[8,]    1    0    1    0    0    1
```

I want to do this for every possible swap in each column and then for all columns to obtain all the possible matrices.

Comment: How are you getting 16? All possible pairings of `n` entities should be `n*(n-1)/2`. For 8 rows, this should be 8*7/2 = 28.

Comment: @ArtemSokolov I was thinking there are 4 zeros and 4 ones, so then there 16. I'm not sure.

Comment: @useR Yes, I only need to swap 1's and 0's

Comment: If I understand correctly you want every permutation on each column, and every possible combination of columns? If I counted properly that is: `prod(choose(ncol(M), rowSums(M)))` or 540M matrices. Is that what you want?

Comment: @useR I think that's the same thing. That would be every ordering of 0s and 1s, no?

Comment: @dayne I don't need to permute the columns. Only the swapping 1's and 0's in the first column, second column, and so on.

Comment: @rxk011 Is `c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)` a valid column 2?

Comment: @useR If we start from the first column, I need all the possible matrices by swapping 1's and 0's and then continue to other columns.

Comment: (Just to clarify I had a "moment" have been speaking about rows rather than columns. Whoops!)

Comment: @useR Sorry. That is one possiblity

Comment: Then, while my calculations were on rows rather than columns, the idea was correct. `prod(choose(nrow(M), colSums(M)))` is actually many more.

Comment: @useR You are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution:

```
# Return all unique permutations for c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)
library(gtools)
perms = unique(permutations(8, 8, M[,1], set = FALSE))

# Create nested list
Mat_list = lapply(vector("list", ncol(M)), function(x) vector("list", nrow(perms)))

# Loop through every column and every permutations replacing each column 
# with each unique permutation one at a time
for(ii in 1:ncol(M)){
  for(jj in 1:nrow(perms)){
    New_Mat = M
    New_Mat[,ii] = perms[jj,]
    Mat_list[[ii]][[jj]] = New_Mat 
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
> Mat_list[[1]][[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    1    0    1
[3,]    1    1    0    0    1    1
[4,]    1    0    0    1    1    0
[5,]    0    0    1    1    1    1
[6,]    1    1    1    0    1    0
[7,]    0    1    1    1    0    0
[8,]    1    0    1    0    0    1
```

**Note:**

Instead of creating a super long list, I've created a nested list of matrices with 8 elements and n sub-elements per element (where n is the number of unique permutations). You can unlist the result if you prefer the long list form.

Comment: @dayne One column at a time yes, but it outputs all possible permutations for each column while keeping the others fixed (removing duplicates), which is what the OP asked for.

Comment: I see. I wonder what the OP actually wants. Every possible combinations of columns? Or rather all matrices with every variation on a single column, giving `sum(choose(nrow(M), colSums(M)))` possibilities.

Comment: @dayne From my understanding, I think you're supposed to only permute one column at a time while keeping others fixed, doing this for all the columns. Let's see what OP says.

Comment: @dayne No offense guys. I need only to permute single column at a time while keeping other columns fixed.

Comment: @useR Is it possible to extend this code to select two columns at a time and do the swap only those two columns while keeping others fixed?

Comment: @rxk011 That will be trickier and is not what you asked in the original question. Can you at least confirm whether my solution works for the one column case?

Comment: @rxk011 That is a completely different question.

Answer (score 1):

This code gives every permutation of `0`s and `1`s by column. I used a smaller toy example here, because the number of possibilities can get very large -- `prod(choose(nrow(M), colSums(M)))`. As a note, this will likely not run on a standard computer for the matrix given, because of memory requirements.

```
library(gtools)
set.seed(1234)
M <- matrix(sample(0:1, 16, replace = TRUE), ncol = 4)
M
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0    1    1    0
# [2,]    1    1    1    1
# [3,]    1    0    1    0
# [4,]    1    0    1    1    

perm1s <- function(n, N) {
  unique(permutations(N, N, c(rep(0, N - n), rep(1, n)), FALSE, FALSE))
}

createMat <- function(vec, lst) {
  tmp <- lapply(seq_along(vec), function(x) lst[[x]][vec[x], ])
  do.call(cbind, tmp)
}

makeMats <- function(M) {

  sums <- colSums(M)
  rows <- nrow(M)

  rowPerm <- lapply(sums, perm1s, N = rows)
  comb <- expand.grid(lapply(sapply(rowPerm, nrow), seq))
  comb <- lapply(split(comb, seq(nrow(comb))), unlist)

  mats <- lapply(comb, createMat, lst = rowPerm)
  mats

}

res <- makeMats(M)
res[[1]]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    0    0    1    0
# [2,]    1    0    1    0
# [3,]    1    1    1    1
# [4,]    1    1    1    1
```

To hold other columns constant when varying 1 column -- `sum(choose(nrow(M), colSums(M)))` possibilities:

```
makeMats2 <- function(M) {

  sums <- colSums(M)
  rows <- nrow(M)

  rowPerm <- lapply(sums, perm1s, N = rows)
  ind <- rep(seq_along(rowPerm), sapply(rowPerm, nrow))
  rowPerm <- lapply(rowPerm, function(x) split(x, seq(nrow(x))))
  rowPerm <- unlist(rowPerm, recursive = FALSE)
  mats <- rep(list(M), length(rowPerm))
  mats <- mapply(function(x, y, z) {x[ , y] <- z; x}, 
                 x = mats, y = ind, z = rowPerm, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
  mats

}
```

Comment: I don't need to change the values. Only "swapping"

Comment: Corrected. I used `rbind` rather than the correct `cbind`.